# Random timeout between ec2 instances in same az

Tags: amazon-ec2, linux-networking, aws-ec2

My elastic-based monitoring system will quite often report timeout on an http check where target is the AWS EC2 instance.
Check is performed from another EC2 instance in same region, same AZ, same subnet (but it's reaching public IP rather than private IP).

I cannot figure out where exactly is the problem, but according to wildfly logs, traffic doesn't even reach the application, however when performing tcpdump, i see packets arrived on destination and destination tries to reply.

Here is a snippet of tcpdump log when traffic just suddenly stops (recorded on receiving endpoint)

```
02:29:21.468733 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 63, id 50556, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    ec2-pu-bl-ic-ip.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com.54138 > ip-172-31-17-107.eu-central-1.compute.internal.https: Flags [S], cksum 0x9bcd (correct), seq 110066568, win 62727, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2736748378 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
02:29:21.468771 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    ip-172-31-17-107.eu-central-1.compute.internal.https > ec2-pu-bl-ic-ip.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com.54138: Flags [S.], cksum 0x4592 (incorrect -> 0x6ade), seq 2350778599, ack 110066569, win 26847, options [mss 8961,sackOK,TS val 638903455 ecr 2736748378,nop,wscale 7], length 0
02:29:21.468931 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 63, id 50557, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    ec2-pu-bl-ic-ip.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com.54138 > ip-172-31-17-107.eu-central-1.compute.internal.https: Flags [.], cksum 0x1dec (correct), seq 1, ack 1, win 491, options [nop,nop,TS val 2736748378 ecr 638903455], length 0
02:29:21.475997 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 63, id 50558, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 569)
    ec2-pu-bl-ic-ip.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com.54138 > ip-172-31-17-107.eu-central-1.compute.internal.https: Flags [P.], cksum 0x1a5e (correct), seq 1:518, ack 1, win 491, options [nop,nop,TS val 2736748385 ecr 638903455], length 517
02:29:21.476022 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 55076, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    ip-172-31-17-107.eu-central-1.compute.internal.https > ec2-pu-bl-ic-ip.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com.54138: Flags [.], cksum 0x458a (incorrect -> 0x1cee), seq 1, ack 518, win 219, options [nop,nop,TS val 638903457 ecr 2736748385], length 0
```

We can see in last line, server responded back to host which is performin check, tcpdump on host performing the check, also receives that packet:

```
02:42:37.742465 IP ec2-pu-bl-ic-ip.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com.https > elk-lb.57714: Flags [.], ack 518, win 219, options [nop,nop,TS val 639102523 ecr 2737544651], length 0
```

But nothing happens, instead - timeout occurs.

I will map the hostname to private IP address and try to see if it check will be more reliable that way, but i would like to check for public endpoints to make sure security group settings and network is always ok.